# Change levels from a variable

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, levels

I am doing a little function in order to change the levels of some      variables(factors) from a data set for other levels that come from      another data set (both with same name of variables).

The main code line to solve the problem would be:

```
data1$variable <- factor(data1$variable, levels= levels(data2$variable))
a<- factor(c(1,2,3,4))
b<- factor(c(1,2,3))
a<- factor(a, levels=levels(b))
a
[1] 1    2    3    <NA>
```

And adding a loop for going through all the columns could be done with:

```
list_levels_d2 <- sapply(d2, levels)
names_d1 <- colnames(d1)
for(i in 1:length(names_d1)){
     d1[, names_d1[i]] <- factor(d1[, names_d1[i]], levels= list_levels_d2[[i]])
   }
```

Basically I wanted to ask if anybody can figure out how to make the same but avoiding the loop "for" using sapply? apply?

I can´t use this:

```
function(x, y){    
sapply(x, factor, levels= levels(y[, names(x)]))     
}
```

Because in the part `levels(y[, names(x)])`, `x` is not taking one name it takes the whole array of names and the value is NULL

Comment: Please learn how to format a question properly...

Comment: `Map(function(x,y) {factor(x, levels=levels(y))}, d1, d2)` and if it is not working, please consider to update with an example

Comment: The function works nicely ! thanks for the help!! Cheers

Comment: If you insist on using an `apply` function, I think the one you want is `mapply`.  But honestly, I don't see any problem with using the `for` loop in this case.

Comment: @Benjamin `Map` is the wrapper for `mapply`.  The `mapply` by default gives a matrix output which may not be good in this case as it converts the 'factor' to 'character' column when the lengths are the same.  Of course, you can use `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

Initial `levels` of the first dataset ('d1')

```
 lapply(d1, levels)
 #$V1
 #[1] "A" "C" "E"

 #$V2
 #[1] "A" "C" "D" "E"

 #$V3
 #[1] "C" "D" "E"
```

We can try with `Map` to loop over the corresponding columns of both datasets ('d1' and 'd2') and change the levels of each column with the corresponding column level of the second dataset.

```
d1[] <- Map(function(x,y) {factor(x, levels=levels(y))}, d1, d2[names(d1)])
```

Or an option using `lapply` will be loop over the column names

```
d1[] <- lapply(names(d1), function(x) {factor(x, levels=levels(d2[,x]))
                                      })
```

After the change

```
 lapply(d1, levels)
 #$V1
 #[1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"

 #$V2
 #[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "F" "G"

 #$V3
 #[1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"
```

which is the same as the levels of the second dataset

```
 lapply(d2[names(d1)], levels)
 #$V1
 #[1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"

 #$V2
 #[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "F" "G"

 #$V3
 #[1] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H"
```

#### data

```
set.seed(28)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5*3,
                 replace=TRUE), ncol=3))
set.seed(34)
d2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:8], 10*3,
                     replace=TRUE), ncol=3))
set.seed(429)
d2 <- d2[sample(ncol(d2))]
```

Comment: d1 <- data.frame(v1= factor(c(1,1,12,3,4,5)), v2= factor(c(1,2,3,4,5,6)))   
d2 <- data.frame(v1= factor(c(1,1,3,4,5)), v2= factor(c(1,2,3,4,5))) 
d1[] <- Map(function(x,y) {levels(x) <- levels(y);x }, d1$v1, d2$v1)                          It didnt work :/                                                                                         "Error en `levels<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1", "3", "4", "5")) : 
  number of levels differs"                                                                            I didnt know the Map function though! thanks!

Comment: @ErikMartinez I think it has to do with some values not present in the dataset.  Try `Map(function(x,y) {factor(x, levels=levels(y))}, d1, d2)`

Comment: Now I see, that helps me a lot!

Comment: @ErikMartinez But some values will be turned to NA as those levels are not longer part of 'd2'

Comment: And in the other way around? Adding NA´s in d2 on those that are not in d1, which is what I was doing

Comment: @ErikMartinez It is better you update the question with the new example.  I created an example without considering all these cases.